# Differentiation of $\operatorname{tr}(\log^2 (APBP^T A))$ with respect to $P$ when $A$ and $B$ are symmetric positive definite matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to take the derivative of $\operatorname{tr}(\log^2 (APBP^T A))$ with respect to $P$ when $A$ and $B$ are symmetric positive definite matrices. I was trying to solve the problem with the following

\begin{align*}\frac{d}{dP_{jk}}\sum_{ijklmn} (\log^2 (A_{ij}P_{jk}B_{kl}P_{ml}A_{mi})) & = \sum_{ijklmn}\frac{2\log(A_{ij}P_{jk}B_{kl}P_{ml}A_{mi})}{A_{ij}P_{jk}B_{kl}P_{ml}A_{mn}}A_{ij}B_{kl}P_{ml}A_{mi} \\ &= \sum_{ijklmn}\frac{2\log(A_{ij}P_{jk}B_{kl}P_{ml}A_{mi})}{P_{jk}},\end{align*}

and then got stuck here. Any hint to keep going on?

Comment: The logarithm is pointwise?

Comment: Maybe you can try this. https://www.matrixcalculus.org/